How to align a bone orientation to move along global axis
I try to build mechanical parts that have been constructed to move along global axis.
I am now trying to visualize the movement of some parts, but I am unable to perfectly move my objects with the bone along the y axis.
After I've set my keyframes and start moving the objects, the bone fails to position the objects to it's origin place in my model.
I dont know how I can move the bone's tip to match perfectly the global y-axis.


Recalculating roll as I understand, only "recalculates" the axis along the bones orientation, but doesnt moves the bone into the proper position.
